# For measuring IV curves, could you use a current source and measure the voltage?

Tags: current, iv-curve

I was trying to find other experiments that required getting an IV curve but all of them seem to be applying voltage and measuring the current.

Comment: I like to use a variable current source, bipolar in fact, for doing I vs V sweeps in just that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would work.

And if you want to measure a curve where you have essentially the same output voltage for different currents, this is pretty much the only way.

[image: GSOT08C VR/IR]
<sup>source: Vishay [GSOT08C datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/doc?85824)</sup>